# Can I add ads to a Styled Media Receiver?

Tags: ads, adsense, google-cast, chromecast

I am working on a *Chromecast* application, and am considering options to support a paid component (separate app, or in-app purchase) to improve the user experience. The first thing that comes to mind is ads. Since I do not have a server to host a *Custom Media Receiver*, I will be using the *Styled Media Receiver*. Is there a way to add ads to this - such as via Google's *AdSense*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such support is currently available on the Styled or Default receivers. If you want to add video adds, you can potentially stream those first (or whenever you want) and then switch to the main content but that might not be the model you want to have.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is there planned support for this in the future?

Comment: We are looking into some options, no timeline for when/if that happens.